# call_history.db location in iOS 5 or 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, jailbreak

what is location for call history file in iOS 5 or iOS 6. and what is name of call history file.
in iOS 4 call history sqlite file location is

```
"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db"
```

Comment: Is it private or open and can be used for non jailbreak device?

Comment: hi sanjit i traverse all the files in 'private directory' using this code NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath: @"/private/"];
    NSString *nextItem = [NSString string];
    while( (nextItem = [dirnum nextObject])) {
        if ([[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"db"] ||
            [[nextItem pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"sqlitedb"]) {
            if ([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:nextItem]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", nextItem);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: but i dont find even wireless directory in tree

Comment: when i backup my device i got call log in this file '/Users/ajay/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/MobileSync/Backup/'anyguid'/2b2b0084a1bc3a5ac8c27afdf14afb42c61a19ca' on mac. just want to know where it exists on iphone

Comment: In simulator the file system is open to access just because of mac os , in mac os file system is open to access but not for iPod touch/iPhone/iPad for some security reasons how much I know.

Comment: but i accessed it on iphone not on simulator

Comment: but what the path you are providing "'/Users/ajay/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/MobileSync/Backup/'anyguid'/2b2b0084a1bc3a5ac8c27afdf14afb42c61a19ca' " it is showing it is simulator

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22833/discussion-between-ajay-and-sanjit-shaw)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on my jailbroken iOS 5.0.1 iPhone 4, and that file is in the exact same location:

```
/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db
```